# Powershell move duplicates to a different folder

Tags: powershell

I need to spawn through a directory to find duplicates using PowerShell. Skip the first one in the list of duplicate files and move the rest to another folder. I got the below script for a start, but could you help me with how to implement the move rest of the files.

```
Trap { continue }
$Date = Get-Date
Get-ChildItem *.* -Recurse | 
Where-Object { $_.LastAccessTime -lt $Date.AddDays(-2555) } | 
Get-FileHash | 
Group-Object -Property Hash | 
Where-Object Count -gt 1 | 
ForEach-Object { $_.group | Select-Object -skip 1 } | 
<move the files>
```

Comment: how are you going to handle name collisions?

Comment: Lee, longtime no see! @Iswar, I have the same thought process as lee here. How are you going to handle same name files?

Comment: Withstanding @Lee_Dailey 's concern, your approach is actually pretty sensible. Do you think you will encounter counts higher than 2? Have you tested this code and if so what's the error or other issue?

Comment: Is `Trap{}` still a thing?

Comment: Yes, in some cases there will be more than 2 duplicates. I think we can overwrite in that case... or the duplicates will be on different folders, maybe we can mimic the folder structure on the target folder and copy them over... I think having a copy should suffice.

Comment: @Steven, yes Trap { } worked for me to skip errors. Yes did test this code.. It is working...

Answer (score 1):

Given comments on the original question the exact requirements aren't clear.  Name collisions are only possible if the same name is encountered in different sub-folders.  Therefore, all the files with the same hash have the same data and "possibly" the same name.  Assuming there's a real potential for name collisions AND a need to copy all but the first of the files in a given hash group the key piece would look something like:

```
... |
  ForEach-Object { 
    $_.Group | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Move-Item -Force -Destination $otherFolder
  }
```

It's important to note this will move everything except the first file in the group. i.e. if you have 3 files in the group it will move the last 2. If there's a name collision among those 2, the 2nd will overwrite the 1st and you will only have that file in the destination.

Note: The code may perform somewhat better if you move the `Move-Item` command after the `ForEach-Object` loop, like:

```
... |
  ForEach-Object { 
    $_.Group | Select-Object -Skip 1
  } |
Move-Item -Force -Destination $otherFolder
```

In this case the `[FileInfo]` objects will be emitted from the loop piped to and consumed by `Move-Item`

---

Now, considering the stated ambivalence to overwrites I suspect the summary requirement is to simply get "a" copy of the data irrespective of file name.  Moreover, given there's been no discussion of sorting, or other selection criteria to determine which file to skip, it may be fine to use `-Last 1` instead.  This might be more efficient in cases where there's more than 2 files in the group.  However, it won't move 2nd... files in a group that have different names which is what distinguishes this approach from `-Skip 1`.

```
... |
  ForEach-Object { 
    $_.Group | Select-Object -Last 1 | Move-Item -Force -Destination $otherFolder
  }
```

Thanks to @mklement0, for helping to identify and distinguish between these 2 approaches.

---

**Additional Information:**

I also think you should filter out directories.  The directory objects will cause `Get-Hash` to error.  Doing so is quite simple:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.* -File |
...
```

Generally speaking, it's better to avoid errors where you know they can occur and can indeed avoid them.

I suspect the `Trap{ continue }` statement was to deal with the errors coming from `Get-Hash`.  Notwithstanding the potential need for error handling elsewhere That could have been handled by setting `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

A Consolidated Example:

```
$DateBound = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2555)
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.* -File | 
Where-Object { $_.LastAccessTime -lt $DateBound } | 
Get-FileHash -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
Group-Object -Property Hash | 
Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 } | 
ForEach-Object { 
    $_.Group | 
    Select-Object -Last 1 |
    Move-Item -Force -Destination $otherFolder
}
```

Note: Above I calculated the date boundary in variable `DateBoundary` beforehand. This is more efficient because you don't have to recalculate the date for every file encountered.

In general, I'd avoid `Trap{}` it's antiquated, and the favored approach is the `Try{}` `Catch{}` `Finally{}`, Recommended reading: [about_Try_Catch_Finally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.1).

One last thing; You were mixing simplified syntax with traditional syntax.  I never use simplified and I don't know if there's a community opinion on it.  However, at a minimum, I would advise staying consistent within a given unit of code.

Comment: Your code works fine when the folder and files are in MB... This Code exits out and moves none of the files when it is 100GB. I am running the shell script on a network drive. The main issue is there are a bunch of directories there which I don't have access to. The error suppression in try catch like you mentioned helps through that; seems like there is a threshold on those? I am not sure, yet. Thanks though, still need to find the solution :-/

Comment: You are likely hitting a performance bottle neck. I'm guessing at this point, but `Group-Object` has to  wait to receive all the objects from `Get-Hash` before it'll return. hence the delay is going to compound as the data set gets larger.  Running a hash on even a 1GB file can be slow.  Otherwise I can't be certain.

Comment: So is there any workarounds you can think of? I know CCleaner is a tool which can find duplicates. Is there any other way I can possibly move all the duplicate items off of the drive?

Comment: I'm really not sure.  We could probably improve upon the performance of `Group-Object` using a hash table keys on the file hash, but my sense is it would yield only marginal improvement. It takes progressively longer to calculate the hash as the file get bigger. You need to test the sub commands on the larger files and do a little math to see what may have the potential for improvement.